# How to find "hidden" padding/margin

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

Using developer tools, I have tried to find the reason why my 3 tabs are taking up the full width of the page. The site is:

http://pages.purolator.com/en/courier-shipping-services/

For some reason, the larger the page, the more padding or margin gets added to the right-hand side of the tab control.

Can someone please help me identify this invisible margin/padding???

Answer (score 1):

The width of the `li` elements is 30%, so together they take up only 90% of the page width.

You can change it to 33.33333%, which is an approximation, but close enough. However, this will get you in trouble, because of the margins on the `li` elements. This margin is added to their width.

A solution would be to remove the margins from the `li` elements. If you want to show some space inbetween, you can do that by making the `li` elements merely a container for a div that looks like a tab. But then I'm getting in too many details, while maybe you have your own ideas on how to solve this.

Here is how it could look:

```
<ul>
    <li><div>This is tab 1</div></li>
    <li><div>This is tab 2</div></li>
    <li><div>This is tab 3</div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* Set box-sizing to border-box so you can add padding without affecting the width of the box */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0 0.2em;
    /* This element should consume 100/elementCount% of its parent. */
    width: 33.33333%;
}

li div {
    /* Style this as a tab. */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/skJQ9/

Comment: This doesn't actually work with the current layout of the site, mind you.

Comment: Well, the main purpose of this answer is to explain where the gap comes from. I see the flaw in just making it '33.33333%' wide, but since it's almost a complete page, I shouldn't have to rewrite his entire CSS. Do you truly think this answer is 'not useful'?

Answer (score 0):

as @GolezTrol said, it's only 30% width, and you have margins inherited, you can use google chrome developer tools to see the computed values.

You should break the inheritance using the !important tag, and then adjust the width to be close to the (100/3 %).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the LI:

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
  width: 33.33%;
  margin: 0; /* for left and right this MUST be 0 */
  padding: 0.1em 0.2em; /* replace margin with padding */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* make sure that the padding is included in your 33.33% and not added */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li:last-child {
width: 33.34%; /* so it adds up to 100% and not to 99.99% */
}
```

Comment: Razvan, that seems to be on the right track but when I add padding to the "li" it doesn't separate the tabs, it just expands the tabs.

Comment: Background for the tabs should be given to the <a> inside them. So, add a padding to the li (like padding: 0 5px;) and set the background for the tabs on the a, adding a { display: block; width: 100%; }